# List Directories / Files in PHP Recursively and Ignore the ones in array

Tags: php, recursion

I'm trying to list directories recrusively in PHP using the RecursiveDirectoryIterator and RecursiveIteratorIterator, but the thing is, i need to ignore some directories and files within..

This is what i have so far..

```
// Define here the directory you have platform installed.
//
$path = 'testing';

// List of directories / files to be ignored.
//
$ignore_new = array(
# Directories
#
'.git',
'testing/dir1',
'testing/dir2',
'testing/dir3',
'testing/dir8',
'public',

# Files
#
'.gitignore',
'.gitmodules',
'.CHANGELOG.md',
'.README.md',
);


$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach (new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename => $object)
{
    echo $filename . '<br />';
}
```

I've tried different ways to check if the directory/file is in the array, but or it doesn't work, or the directory is not ignored completly...

This an example of the directory structure

```
testing\
testing\.git
testing\.git\files & directories
testing\testing\dir1
testing\testing\dir2
testing\testing\dir3
testing\testing\dir8
testing\.gitignore
testing\.gitmodules
testing\CHANGELOG.md
testing\README.md
```

Is this possible, or i need to use the old fashion way to recursive list directories/files in PHP ?

Thanks !

Answer (score 3):

You should always use `Full Path` since you are combining file and folder

```
$path = __DIR__;

// List of directories / files to be ignored.
//
$ignoreDir = array('1.MOV.xml','.git','testing/dir1','testing/dir2','testing/dir3','testing/dir8','public');

/**
 * Quick patch to add full path to Ignore
 */
$ignoreDir = array_map(function ($var) use($path) {
    return $path . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $var;
}, $ignoreDir);

$ite = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($path, FilesystemIterator::SKIP_DOTS);
foreach ( new RecursiveIteratorIterator($ite) as $filename => $object ) {

    if (in_array($filename, $ignoreDir))
        continue;

    echo $filename . '<br />';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach using `RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator`:

```
<?php

$f_filter = function ($o_info) {
   $s_file = $o_info->getFilename();
   if ($s_file == '.git') {
      return false;
   }
   if ($s_file == '.gitignore') {
      return false;
   }
   return true;
};

$o_dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator('.');
$o_filter = new RecursiveCallbackFilterIterator($o_dir, $f_filter);
$o_iter = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($o_filter);

foreach ($o_iter as $o_info) {
   echo $o_info->getPathname(), "\n";
}
```

https://php.net/class.recursivecallbackfilteriterator